# Does allying with one side lock you out of promotion quests or other content?

Tags: might-and-magic-8-day-of-destroyer

Long before skyrim made choosing a side popular, Might and magic 8 already did it. For example you have to choose to help the dragons, or the dragon hunters. If you pick the side of the dragons, for example, which content are you locked out of? Can you still use the shops of the dragon hunters? Can you still talk to the NPC's in the houses? Can you still do the other sides promotion quest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no". As soon as you pick the side, other's side world NPCs become hostile, and in-house NPCs refuse to talk to you, so shops and promotion quest is locked out. It is true for dragon-dragonhunter quest and necromancer-cleric quest both. It is quite possible to promote everyone long before you have to take a side, though.